# Rails, thinking sphinx configure task not working... no output either

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I don't get it, and I'm wondering if anyone else has had a similar problem with thinking sphinx.

```
rails@myapp:~/apps/myapp/current$ rake ts:conf --trace RAILS_ENV="production"(in /home/rails/apps/myapp/releases/20110124214031)
** Invoke ts:conf (first_time)
** Invoke thinking_sphinx:configure (first_time)
** Invoke thinking_sphinx:app_env (first_time)
** Execute thinking_sphinx:app_env
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute thinking_sphinx:configure
Generating Configuration to /home/rails/apps/myapp/releases/20110124214031/config/production.sphinx.conf
Killed
```

This is what my `sphinx.yml` looks like as well:

```
development:
  port: 9312
test:
  port: 9312
production:
  port: 9312
  pid_file: /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid
  searchd_files: /home/rails/apps/myapp/shared/db/sphinx
```

It's soo annoying because it used to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I helped someone with this problem the other day, and it turned out it was actually a different out-of-date plugin that was causing the issue. That said, could be something else here...

To debug, I'd recommend commenting out all `define_index` blocks, and add them back one by one, and see if it's one in particular that's causing it. If so, then comment out all fields and attributes, and add them back one by one (though you'll need one field to start with - otherwise TS/Sphinx complains).

Otherwise, what versions of Rails and Thinking Sphinx are you using? If you narrow it down to a define_index block, what's in that block? What are the associations that block refers to, if any?

Comment: Oh hey Pat, thanks for responding, you've done such an excellent job, and I've never had a problem with your Gem as its so soundly built, thanks again for the help!

Comment: Hey pat, it totally stalls at the task "thinking_sphinx:app_env" after taking your advice, i'm wondering can I just create the conf file by hand?

Comment: It's odd that thats the task it stalls on. All that does is invoke the environment rake task from Rails, and sets the Rails configuration setting cache_classes to false. Does your app stall if you run 'rake environment'?

Comment: And I don't recommend creating the conf file by hand - especially given that this problem sounds like it's a bit bigger than TS (although not ruling TS out as the source).